# how can I overwrite the content of a file to another file

Tags: command, command-prompt

for example if I want to overwrite the content of file1.txt to 'my file' what command should I use?

i tried to overwrite file name to another file name

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
copy /y file1.txt "my file"
```